# How to make a cell in a row show date of most recent edit within that row

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, formula

I'm working in Google Sheets on what is going to be a regularly accessed and edited document. What I would like is to have a column labelled "Date of Last Edit" and for each cell in that column to reflect the date of each cell row most recent edit. For example, if I edit info in cell C3 then I want the cell in column "Date of Last Edit" Row 3 to reflect the date I made the edit. I've found a few that are run by column but they only work for an individual column. I need it to cover all cells in a row that fall in front of "Date of Last Edit."

Answer (score 1):

add this script to your sheet and change format and time zone if you need so (`"GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy"`):

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 

  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();

  // note: actRng = the cell being updated
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var cindex = actRng.getColumnIndex();

  var dateCol = sheet.getLastColumn();  
  var lastCell = sheet.getRange(index,dateCol);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd.MM.yyyy");

  lastCell.setValue(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will update C:C with the email address of the user, and D:D with the current time of the same row if A:B are edited on the Data Entry tab. You'll need to set up an onChange() trigger to get it to work.

```
function userUpdate() {
    /* 
    Changed the updated by/on to make it faster
    Put in handling to make sure that if they delete a cell, that it only clears out the submitted by/on if ALL the values in A:B are blank
    */

    // Main sheet details
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var spreadsheetTimeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
    var lastUpdatedString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), spreadsheetTimeZone, "MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
    var sessionEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

    // Check Sheet
    if (s.getName() == "Data Entry") { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        var row = r.getRowIndex();
        var column = r.getColumn();
        var activeRange = s.getRange("A" + row + ":B" + row);
        //var activeRangeValues = 
        var activeRangeValuesLength = activeRange.getValues().toString().length;

        if (row > 1) {

            // Declare variables

            var cellValue = r.getValue().toString();

            // If the cellValue IS blank
            if (activeRangeValuesLength < 5) {
                sessionEmail = "";
                lastUpdatedString = "";
            }

            //  Update Submitted By / Submitted On
            if (column < 5) {
              var lastUpdatedBy = s.getRange("C" + row)
              lastUpdatedBy.setValue(sessionEmail); // update column C 

              var lastUpdated = s.getRange("D" + row)
              lastUpdated.setValue(lastUpdatedString); // update column D    

            }
        }
    }
```